# Android Notification with pending URL-Intent - only by clicking the notification

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, notifications

I'm trying to create a pending URL-Intent for a Notification, that is called, if the user clicks the notification.

The problem is that the Intent is being called by creating the notification, so the url is getting called in the web browser immediatly. I want to prevent this, but do not know how?

Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.com"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyApp.getContext(), 0, intent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApp.getContext(), "MyApp")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("my App")
                    .setContentText("Click here to call the URL")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("...."))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    ;

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MyApp.getContext());

notificationManager.notify(getNotificationId(), builder.build());
```

How can I prevent executing the intent after the "notify" call??

Intent should only be executed, when the user clicks on the Notification.

Comment: "The problem is that the Intent is being called by creating the notification..." – That seems highly unlikely. Are you sure you're not starting that `Intent` yourself somewhere? Or otherwise launching the browser? What happens if you put just the posted code into a fresh project?

Comment: Can anybody help on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I was trying to help, but you haven't answered my questions. Simply posting a `Notification` will not automatically fire its `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your help. Now I got it working, was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this:
public void notification()
{
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"));

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant") PendingIntent pending = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
String channelId = getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = null;
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = 
 NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelId,  
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationChannel.setDescription(channelId);
    notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .setContentTitle("my App")
        .setContentText("Click here to call the URL")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("...."))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(pending)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        ;


  notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```